# Power Query convert of 3 byte binary date getting variable wasn't recognized

Tags: powerbi

Date displays as 3byte hex value example = 72, 02, 11
Converts to 72 to decimal = 114 + 1900 = 2014, 02 = 02, 11 = 17
So date is 02/17/2014

Bdate comes in as a three byte field, binary so defined
1st byte = year, 2nd byte = mth, 3rd byte = day.

Building a function to call because several dates in data base are of this format.
Secondary function to convert hex to decimal is fnhex2Dec from a library.
Here is code for FixDateBn

```
    let
        FixDateBn = (Bdate as binary) =>
    
        let
        FixDateBn = BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(
        BinaryFormat.Record ([
                Yr= BinaryFormat.Byte,       //<- the Yr variable is getting Name Yr wasn't recognized.
                Mth = BinaryFormat.Byte,
                Day = BinaryFormat.Byte ]),
            ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
                Yrnum = fnhex2Dec(Yr,16)+1900,
                Mthnum = fnhex2Dec(Mth,16),
                Daynum = fnhex2Dec(Day,16),
            Gooddate = #date(Yrnum,Mthnum,Daynum) as date
        in 
            if Bdate is null then null else Gooddate
    in
        FixDateBn
```

Appreciate any help.

Here is the sql that converts from hex to regular date. Don't know how to do this in Power Query M language.

```
CREATE FUNCTION "GetDateFromWDate" (:wDate CHAR(3)) RETURNS DATE AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE :tmpdate DATE
    SET :tmpdate = '1900-01-01';   
    IF (:wDate <> null) and (:wDate <> '') THEN
        SET :tmpdate = DATEFROMPARTS (ascii(substring(:wDate, 1, 1)) + 1900, ascii(substring(:wDate, 2, 1)), ascii(substring(:wDate, 3, 1)));
    END IF;   
    RETURN :tmpdate;
END
```

Thanks
Sammy

Comment: Here is the sql that converts the date from hex to regular date format.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION "GetDateFromWDate" (:wDate CHAR(3)) RETURNS DATE AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE :tmpdate DATE
    SET :tmpdate = '1900-01-01';   
    IF (:wDate <> null) and (:wDate <> '') THEN
        SET :tmpdate = DATEFROMPARTS (ascii(substring(:wDate, 1, 1)) + 1900, ascii(substring(:wDate, 2, 1)), ascii(substring(:wDate, 3, 1)));
    END IF;   
    RETURN :tmpdate;
END